# webpack serve — no output files created, but my web app runs fine

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I’m a couple of days into using webpack … so far so good.

Question:

I’m testing with webpack-dev-server … when I run `webpack serve`, it doesn’t appear to write any files to my webpack output folder … but my web app loads up fine, is debuggable, etc.

When using `webpack serve`, is everything being done from memory, or are my “regular” source/asset files being used in this case, or is something else occurring?

I’m using the latest webpack and webpack-dev-server node modules.

Thanks.
-lagouyn

Comment: webpack-dev-server doesn't write any output files after compiling. Instead, it keeps bundle files in memory and serves them as if they were real files mounted at the server's root path. See https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-server